# How to access local function variable in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, lambda, local-variables, google-chrome-console

```
var MyFunc =
  MyFunc ||
  (function (u, p) {....})
```

If this code is in a file named `abc.js` and there multiple JS files for the website, how do I print the variable `u` in chrome's console?

I tried `console.log(u)`, `console.log(MyFunc.u)` both didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. `u` is a parameter of a function. It only exists while the function is being executed and even then it's value depends on the parameters you pass to `MyFunc`. What would you expect it to be when I call `MyFunc(1); MyFunc(2); MyFunc(3);`? `u` has had 3 different values.

Comment: Values doesn't matter, I just want the value printed in console. I want to do it on a live website.

Comment: `console.log(u)` (or in the console itself simply `u`) should show you the value as long as the debugger is paused inside that function expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand that correctly, you can do this:

```js
var MyFunc =
  MyFunc ||
  (function (u, p) {
      console.log(u);
      console.log(p);
   }
  );

MyFunc(1, 2);
```

When you run the above code, it will assign anonymous function to MyFunc and then you need to call that function definition by passing the parameters.

Comment: How do I do it on a live website? I paused the program in debugger, edited the file, hit ctrl+s and resumed still nothing was printed in console.

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida Why do you need to print the values when you can already inspect the values in the debugger?

Comment: @Ivar I can't find the variable ```u``` to add it in watch.

Comment: On a live website you need to put breakpoints in the JS file and once that code is being executed, you can add that in the global variable if that you want, However, if you want to print value on console, you should use console API.

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida, the value of 'u' will be based on the param being passed to it and you should add the break point and while you are in that function you can type in 'u' in console and the value will be printed.

Comment: hope this helps you :https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/watch-variables#:~:text=To%20add%20a%20variable%20to,variable%20as%20it%20is%20added.

Comment: The code gets executed immediately after I hit refresh, I added breakpoint and refreshed and the breakpoint was lost.

Comment: You should enable the breakpoint, once you enable(active) any breakpoint on the website it won't be lost unless you continue it.